# deny access to file in a directory with htaccess working locally not remotely

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I want to deny remote access to files in a directory on my web server. I've set up a simple .htaccess file that works nicely on my local server (Windows based)

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

But when i load the file on my remote server (Apache 2.4 on a AMI machine, a Red Hat based server) the directive is simply ignored.

What are the possible reasons of this behaviour? If I'm not wrong it's not important the apache conf file as the .htaccess file in the directory should overwrite it.

Could be a problem of ownership of file? I uploaded it via ftp so it's a ec2-user file, while others are apache. No problem with php files loaded in the same way though.

I tried also to restart apache, without success.

Comment: The server does not allow to `AllowOverride` for the directory so the `.htaccess` is simply ignored.

Comment: Right! I've changed in the main conf file `AllowOverride` of `html` directory and it worked! Thanks! If you add it as an answer i will mark it as the solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The webserver does not allow to `AllowOverride` for the directory so the `.htaccess` is simply ignored.